# Golang email sending through jordan-wright/email.v1

Tags: email, go, gmail, certificate

I'm writing web server and I need to send email message through my server. I tried to do as it's written in examples, but I get error:
`EXTRA x509.UnknownAuthorityError=x509: certificate signed by unknown authority`
My code is below:

```
inviteEmail := email.NewEmail() //it was said that email.v1 imported as email
inviteEmail.From = MyEmail
inviteEmail.To = make([]string, 1)
inviteEmail.To[0] = emailstr //is reciever's email
inviteEmail.Subject = "Test"
inviteEmail.Text = []byte("Welcome " + emailstr + " \nYour link is localhost:8080")
err = inviteEmail.Send("smtp.gmail.com:587", smtp.PlainAuth("", MyGmail, MyGmailPassword, "smtp.gmail.com"))
if err != nil {
    logger.Error("ERROR : ", err)
} else {
    logger.Info("Email sent")
}
```

upd: I tried to use both MyGmail and MyGmailLogin (without @gmail.com) in PalinAuth but I always get error.

Has anybody faced it? Maybe problem is because server is on localhost?

Comment: The error has nothing to do with your authentication, that's a TLS error. What do you mean by "server is on localhost"? Do you have "smtp.gmail.com" resolving to 127.0.0.1?

Comment: _What do you mean by "server is on localhost"?_  (@JimB )  
I mean  my server is not on www.address.com, but just on localhost:8080.

_Do you have "smtp.gmail.com" resolving to 127.0.0.1?_  (@JimB )  
I don't know. I'm sorry, I'm quite new in web, and also I may have some translation problem. If you mean "does it ping?" so answer is yes, it pings well.  

What do I need to check and how? Thank you

Comment: I guess it was unsuccessfull to notify you, your username wasnt highlighted @JimB

Comment: Are you getting the certificate error connecting to `smtp.gmail.com`, or to your server on localhost?

Comment: I guess while connecting to smtp.gmail.com because my server actually works (website is on)
But when I try 
`err = inviteEmail.Send("smtp.gmail.com:587", smtp.PlainAuth("", MyGmail, MyGmailPassword, "smtp.gmail.com"))`
Then I have such error

Comment: @JImB maybe there is a problem, because my golang version is 1.3?

Comment: Guess it's not - I've updated

Comment: It sounds like your OS isn't providing the correct or up to date root CAs to verify the certificate.

Comment: @JimB is there way to improve it? I am using Lubuntu 15.04 (Lubuntu requires not so much resources and this is useful because my server is on virtual machine: (Oracle VM))

Comment: Why a desktop system when the standard ubuntu server image is much smaller? Regardless, you need to troubleshoot the CA problem.  Make sure you have all OS updates installed. At lease try connecting to the mail server outside your program and verify the cert, either with Go and/or another client, so you can tell if it's your code or the system configuration. This isn't really programming related, and stackoverflow isn't the right forum to walk you through all the possible steps you could take.

Comment: Ok, Thank you @JimB
I will try to find my problem out, I thought I can improve it programmly, but I don't, I will try.
And I don't use server image yet, because I have tuned up Lubuntu (I used it much times for some university stuff, so I needed it to be desktop)